# Keeping Data on Form

Tags: php, validation, user-registration

I have a register form which is post data without refresh page! My problem form reset datas. It works on username and keeping user's entry. I try to do same thing for "gender" too, but if i get eror, "Genderselection get reset too.I couldn't manage keep it.

Can anyone help me please?

My code is below:

```
/* Current Page */
    public function currentPage() {
        /* Current Page */
        $currentPage  = 'http';
        if(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == "on") {$currentPage .= "s";}
        $currentPage .= "://";
        $currentPage .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        return $currentPage;
    }

    /* Register */
    public function register() {
    global $database;

    /* Set Message Array */
    $message = array();

    /* Check if Login is set */
    if(isset($_POST['register'])) {

    /* Check Username */
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {

    $check_username = strtolower($_POST['username']);

    /* Check the username length */
    $length = strlen($check_username);
    if($length >= 5 && $length <= 25) {

    /* Is the username Alphanumeric? */
    if(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', $check_username)) {
    $error[] = "Please enter a valid alphanumeric username";
    $username = null;
    } else {
    $database->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username', array(':username' => $check_username));

    /* Check if user exist in database */
    if($database->count() == 0) {

    /* Require use to validate account */
    if($this->email_verification == true) {

    /* Check if user exist in inactive database */
    $database->query('SELECT date FROM users_inactive WHERE username = :username', array(':username' => $check_username));

    /* If user incative is older than 24 hours */

    $user = $database->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if($database->count() == 0 or time() >= strtotime($user->date) + 86400) {

    /* If user incative is older than 24 hours */
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    } else {
    $error[] = "Username already in use";
    $username = $check_username;
    }
    } else {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
    } else {
    $error[] = "Username already in use";
    $username = $check_username;
    }
    }
    } else {
    $error[] = "Please enter a username between 5 to 25 characters";
    $username = $check_username;
    }
    } else {
    $error[] = "Please enter a username";
    $username = null;
    }

    /* Check Password */
    if(!empty($_POST['password'])) {

    /* Do passwords match? */

    if(isset($_POST['password_again']) && $_POST['password_again'] == $_POST['password']) {

    /* Is the password long enough? */
    $length = strlen($_POST['password']);
    if($length >= 8) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    } else {
    $error[] = "Passwords must be atleast than 8 characters";
    }
    } else {
    $error[] = "Passwords must match";
    }
    } else {
    $error[] = "Please enter a password";
    }


    /* Check Gender */
    if(empty($_POST['gender'])) {
    $error[] = "Please choose your gender";
    }else{

    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

                }


    $form = '
    <form name="register" action="' . $this->currentPage() . '" method="post">
    <label><span>Username</span>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="' . $username . '" />
    </label>

    <label><span>Password</span>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    </label>

    <label><span>Password Again</span>
    <input type="password" name="password_again" />
    </label>

    <label><span>Gender:</span>
    <select name="gender" value="' . $gender . '">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>

    <input name="register" type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
            ';
            /* Combine Data */
            $data = "";
            /* Report any Info */
            if(isset($info)) {
                foreach($info as $message) {
                $data .= '<div class="notice info">' . $message . '</div>';
                }
            }
            /* Report any Errors */
            if(isset($error)) {
                foreach($error as $message) {
                $data .= '<div class="notice error">' . $message . '</div>';
                }
            }
            /* Report any Success */
            if(isset($success)) {
                foreach($success as $message) {
                $data .= '<div class="notice success">' . $message . '</div>';
                }
            }

            /* Return data */
            return $data;
        }
```

Comment: please indent your code or it makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your "gender" value problem - You need to change this code

```
<select name="gender" value="' . $gender . '">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
```

To

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="" ' .($gender == '' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>Choose</option>
    <option value="Male" ' .($gender == 'male' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>Male</option>
    <option value="Female" ' .($gender == 'female' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>Female</option>
```

You are trying to set a `value` to `select` tag which is invalid.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with this code:

<select name="gender" value="' . $gender . '">
    <option value="" ' .($gender == '' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>Choose</option>
    <option value="Male" ' .($gender == 'Male' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>Male</option>
 <option value="Female" ' .($gender == 'Female' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>Female</option>